# pynamodb - Get DB entries with only hash key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Using [pynamodb](https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB), I want to get all range keys that match a certain hash key in a table.

I know I can do a scan and then filter out entries that match the hash key like so:

```
from pynamodb.models import Model 
from pynamodb.attributes import UnicodeAttribute

class Users(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'user_posts'
    username = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    post_id = UnicodeAttribute(range_key=True)

# Get all post_id's for a username
user = 'johndoe22'
posts = []

for entry in Users.scan():
    if entry.username == user:
        posts.append(entry.post_id)
```

I'd like to move the filtering logic to the query level so I don't have to pull down the entire contents of the db. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use query instead of scan operation. I am not fluent with python so I can't assist you with that but the scan operation is most likely not what you want to use when you want to query using range/hash key take a look at the query operation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html